# Show Windows 8 Taskbar with Touch Screen

Tags: windows-8, taskbar, touchscreen

I have been searching for an answer for this for a while and have not found anything.

On Windows 8 with a touch screen, I have the task bar set to autohide (something I've preferred in Windows forever). With a touch screen, I can't seem to figure out how to get to the taskbar when it autohides. Does anyone know how I can access it using the touch screen?

Comment: I'll check this later, but doesn't a swipe up from the bottom edge do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What I do is to drag from somewhere near the botton edge to the botton edge, this is not a gesture to bring the taskbar up but since it leaves the pointer at the botton edge when you finish the gesture the taskbar pops out. To my knowledge there is no way to show it without using a workaround, looks like MS is trying to get the classic desktop deprecated...

Sorry for such a late reply, I hope this is still relevant.

Cheers.

Answer (score 3):

Right click on the task bar, click properties, disable "Show Windows Store apps on the taskbar", click "Apply" and then "Ok".

Down swipe from an inch above the bottom to off the screen and then up swipe (one quick gesture), and the taskbar will appear.  Tap the screen and the task bar will disappear.

Comment: Unless you're posting from a teletype machine, don't use all caps.  It's the Internet equivalent of screaming.

Comment: Sorry about that.I'm just used to using all caps, ie, drawing construction drawings and typing punch cards... lol

Comment: $DIETY knows why, but this works. Perfectly. I wish I knew wtf the Windows Store Apps have to do with this rediculous behaviour, but removing them made it work exactly like it should in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

There is an app called TouchMe Gesture Studio that comes with plenty of ready made gestures, you can also set your own ones, like two fingers swipe up to show taskbar. You also need a gesture engine, there is a 32 days evaluation version and  I am currently testing it. As for now, the problem is solved for me.

Comment: This reads a bit spammy to me, can you expand upon this answer or perhaps provide some alternatives?

Answer (score 0):

Two methods that work but not always reliably for me.

1) Assuming that the taskbar is at the bottom, find an open area of the desktop and swipe down.  You "might" need to tap the desktop first just to give it focus but not always.

2) If you are in an application, then tap near the bottom of the screen and pull down and back up.  Sometimes just pulling down is enough.  Depends on the application.  In Wordpad a simple swipe down was enough.  In Chrome I have to swipe down and back up.  If Chrome is fullscreen (F11) then nothing works.

Answer (score 0):

I placed the On Screen Keyboard shortcut on the desktop. Once you open the keyboard, press the TAB key, the TaskBar will popup.

No swipe method I tried worked.

Answer (score 0):

I just re-align the tablets touchscreen with my finger from settings control panel and now when I double click on hidden bar at bottom then reveals... strange but it works!

Answer (score 0):

[Iff](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/If_and_only_if#Origin_of_iff) you have a keyboard attached... There are a couple of keyboard-shortcut tricks I found on [this page at winsupersite.com](http://winsupersite.com/article/faqtip/access-the-taskbar-with-keyboard-shortcuts) that do the trick reasonably well.

My current favorite is this one for "Display the Jump list", aka "perform a right-click on one of the icons on your taskbar", which makes it visible:

> Display the Jump List for a particular application or window
>
> To display the Jump List for a particular application or window, tap
>   ALT + WINKEY + #. So, to display the Google Chrome Jump List, I would
>   tap ALT + WINKEY + 3, and then could use the arrow keys to find an
>   item, and then tap ENTER to select it.

Answer (score 0):

Once you have disabled showing apps, you can either swipe down and up like suggested above, or you can tap half on and half off the screen. It seems to be less intrusive (in Chrome that is).

Answer (score -1):

Disable "Show Windows Store Apps on the TaskBar" in the taskbar properties and be happy.

Comment: How would that work?

Comment: Meanwhile, multiple people have confirmed this (in now deleted answers).